# What does $U$ mean when talking about set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I'm studying sets and in their, their is the mathematical definition of a set made up sets.
$$∪M \triangleq \{ x \mid\text{∃m∈M.x∈m}\}$$ 
$$∩M \triangleq \{ x \mid\text{Ɐm∈M.x∈m}\}$$ 
What do $∪M$ and $∩M$ mean? And that tiny dot in the middle of the definition is also confusing me.

Comment: Strangely enough, $\bigcup M$ means $\{x|\exists m\in M.x\in m\}$ and $\bigcap M$ means $\{x|\forall m\in M.x\in m\}.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is a set of sets${}^{\dagger}$, then $\bigcup M$ denotes the *union* of all the sets in $M$, and $\bigcap M$ denotes the *intersection* of all the sets in $M$. Equivalent ways of writing this would be
$$\bigcup M = \bigcup_{m \in M} m \quad \text{and} \quad \bigcap M = \bigcap_{m \in M} m$$

The 'tiny dot' is just notation separating the quantifier from the rest of the statement. You might be more familiar with one of the following conventions
$$(\forall m \in M)(x \in m) \qquad \text{or} \qquad \forall m \in M\ x \in M \qquad \text{or} \qquad \forall m \in M (x \in M)$$
or any one of zillions of other notation conventions for quantifiers. Likewise for $\exists$.

So in summary,

- $\bigcup M = \{ x \mid x \in m \text{ for some } m \in M \}$ is the union of all the sets in $M$; and
- $\bigcap M = \{ x \mid x \in m \text{ for all } m \in M \}$ is the intersection of all the sets in $M$.

In the simple case where $M=\{A,B\}$ for sets $A$ and $B$, then we have
$$\bigcup M = A \cup B \quad \text{and} \quad \bigcap M = A \cap B$$

---

${}^{\dagger}$ *Footnote: in ZF(C), all objects are sets, so all sets are sets of sets.*

Answer (score 0):

For example, if $m_1, \ldots, m_k$ are sets and $M := \{m_1,\ldots,m_k\}$ is the set of these sets, then $\cup M$ means
$$\cup M = m_1 \cup \ldots\cup m_k$$
where $\cup$ means "union of the sets".